# SunTouch underfloor heater without floor sensor?

Tags: thermostat, radiant-heating, retrofit

I have purchased two [SunTouch UnderFloor 16" x 6' long 120V 0.6A](https://www.warmyourfloor.ca/suntouch-underfloor-16-x-6-long-120v-0-6a.html) to retrofit a radiant floor on the one-level-above bathroom without having to remove the floor. The [instruction manual](https://www.warmyourfloor.ca/pub/media/pdf/SunTouch-UnderFloor-Retro-Fit-Mat-Installation-Manual-Current-WYF.pdf) (page 4) indicates that the SunStat floor sensor *"must be installed in the floor with the mat"*. However, my preference would be to control the heating using a 3rd-party thermostat which would trigger based on the ambient temperature in the bathroom.

Does anyone have experience with such system, or explanations as to why the SunStat floor sensor would be absolutely required, as opposed to an ambient temperature thermostat?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the radiant floor could get too hot while the external temperature sensor still indicates below required T.

This could damage the element or part of the floor.

The underfloor heating (water) I fitted had two temperature sensors - one for the ambient and one at the output of the mixing valve to shut down the pump if the output was above a certain value so the pipes did not get damaged through overheating.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense! I do have another electric radiant floor in another bathroom which works with the ambient temperature thermostat and I haven’t had any issue with it, even though we had it on 24/7 for several weeks during other renovations which had left us without heating system.

Answer (score 1):

I run all of my radiant floor heating systems using ambient temperature. I own a radiant heating system - WarmlyYours - and in the last 20 years, I've done both floor and ambient. For me the benefit of ambient is that it takes other heat sources into consideration so I don't over heat a room when I'm getting radiant heat from the sun.  The only time you would need to strictly control the floor temperature would be if you are using some type of wood or laminate product where the manuf specifically requires that a certain floor temperature is maintained.

Comment: Thank you for clearly identifying your background - that lends a lot of credibility to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Did you do any retrofit installations using ambient temperature thermostat? I'll be retrofitting, i.e. installing on the below ceiling, without removing the floor.